# JqueryMobile popup after postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a Jquerymobile popup(in asp.net website) and within that I have a simple textarea and submit button.
After the submit button event, I want to do certain things.
Validation on textarea, if empty show a literal with error message.
If successful, then show a thank you message along with close button.
All this has to be done while the popup is open (after submit).

The problem is, after submit the DOM is refreshed and popup box is closed.

```
<div class="feedback-text">
        <a href="#feedback" data-rel="popup">Feedback</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="feedback" data-overlay-theme="a" data-position-to="window">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <div class="feedback-field-wrapper">                          
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtFeedback" runat="server" Text="*feedback" cssclass="form-first-name" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <center>
        <div class="errormsg-feedback"><asp:literal ID="ltError" runat="server" Text="test" Visible="false"></asp:literal></div>        
            <asp:Button ID="btnFeedback" runat="server" Text="Submit" data-ajax="false" 
                data-icon="arrow-r" style="width:150px;" data-inline="true" /></center>                 
</div>
```

Would you guys suggest if there is a way to keep the popup box open after the submit.

Thanks.

Comment: could u show some code pls? and you can do this only using `localStorage`. There is no other way

Comment: thanks for showing interest, I just added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant do that normally unleass otherwise you use `localStorage` API. This is like a cache system which exists in the browser. From [DiveIntoHTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

> So what is HTML5 Storage? Simply put, it’s a way for web pages to store named key/value pairs locally, within the client web browser. Like cookies, this data persists even after you navigate away from the web site, close your browser tab, exit your browser, or what have you.

You could set a value in `localStorage` in the submit event of `#btnFeedback`, then on page refresh, check if that value exists on page refresh and reopen it.

To set a value :

```
 localStorage["isOpen"] = "1";
```

To check if its `null` or not :

```
 var isOpen = localStorage["isOpen"];
 if ([null, undefined].indexOf(isOpen) == -1) {
        //data exists
 }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/ZJvjJ/

An alternate, better method would be to use ajax to submit your form. This way the page wont refresh and gives the user a nice experience.

Here's  a question which helps you do that : [jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: Thanks hungerpain,
I'd go with ajax way.